# Swift : CGRect interactive?

Tags: swift, uipangesturerecognizer, cgrect

Hi good fellows of the Code.

I'm still trying to figure out how Swift's working, and how to use it to make nice interactive UI. 
Therefore, I'm trying to make an CGRect being draggable, touch-sensible, etc.

I've seen that's it's quite easy to do so with images in the storyboard, but in that case it's not working because the CGRect does not appears in the storyboard as it is generated by the code.

So far, my code is :

```
import UIKit




class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {




var square: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    square = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 200, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100))
    square.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    square.userInteractionEnabled = true

    view.addSubview(square)


}
}
```

It makes a very nice gray square. 
But I can't figure how to make it move. I tried several things, like adding the working code of an IBAction like this :

```
func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
    recognizer.view.center = CGPoint(x:recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
        y:recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y)
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
}
```

But it's returning an Thread 1 SIGBRT error. 
I tried replacing self.view by square, it's not better.

A link with the error : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tp51D.jpg

If someone here can either show me an example or a link related to that topic I would be extremely happy.

Thanks for the help !

EDIT : To be clear, I tried to work it as a classic IBAction, which means I tried to find a way to call the handlePan function. But either it's not how it's intended to work, or I'm just not doing it right.

Comment: hello, can you paste the full error you see?

Comment: Sure ! It's in the AppDelegate class, the first line is highlighted in green and it's noticed : Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT. Nothing much.

Comment: Hopefully this helps with your needs: http://www.raywenderlich.com/76020/using-uigesturerecognizer-with-swift-tutorial